# Unparseable date using SimpleDateFormat Android

Tags: java, android, date

I had a String of a date like that : `27/8/2019 14:6` I try to parse it using  SimpleDateFormat but it gives me this error **Unparseable date**

this is  my code :

```
 SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm a"); 

 Date endDate = spf.parse(new_event_finish_date_value.getText().toString());
 spf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");  

String endDate_value = spf.format(endDate);
```

> //what I'm looking for : 2019-08-31T19:30:45+0200

Comment: **Don't ever use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.** They're obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: your `SimpleDateFormat ` obviously does not match your date string.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your input format to this

```
SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```